# Is there a verb for "to take advice"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a single word for the action of taking someone's advice?

Example sentence:

> I was told to sign the check, and I ________ed [took his advice].

Comment: in this case 'obliged'

Comment: obey / accept / regard etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was told to sign the check and I ***consented***.

Macmillan:

> **[consent](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/consent_2#consent_17)** 
>   *VERB* [INTRANSITIVE]
>
> to agree to do something
>
> The defense must show that the victim had consented.

Answer (score 6):

I was told to sign the check and I [heed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heed)ed the advice.

> Merriam Webster
>
> to give consideration or attention to; pay attention to

Heeding has deeper meanings than what it is appears on the surface. To *heed* someone's advice is to take notice and consider, if not follow completely.

Comment: Your fill-in of the example sentence is incorrect, it is missing the ending. It would need to be "...and I heeded *him*" or "...and I heeded *his advice*".

Comment: @AndyT Good catch. Shouldn't be the intransitive version.

Comment: What would be wrong with 'I was told to sign the check, and I did' please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin There is nothing wrong with it. But this is a different discussion.

Comment: Uh… vickyace, did you notice the question was ‘Is there a verb for “to take advice”… a single word for taking someone's advice?’ I suspect not.

‘Obliging’ the adviser would be ingratiation, not acceptance.

‘Obedience’ is for orders, not advice.

‘Regard’ is to consider, not to take.

‘Consent’ in the context of advice, is to acquiesce, not to take.

How is your own ‘I heeded the advice’ better than ‘I took the advice?’ How are ‘heeded’ or ‘accept’ even different from ’took’, please?

Thanks, vickyace, and the ‘different discussion’ is actually yours.

Happy Easter!

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The first priority is to fit the **verb**ed form, ruling out **did**, and which among the choices is better is yet another *different discussion*.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin you must have missed this bit "**and I ________ed**" the verb ends with the suffix -ed, and I'm pretty sure vickyace's solution "**I heeded**" needs an object.

Comment: Thanks Mari-LouA; vickyace I saw the bit about the putative verb ending with the suffix "…ed" and I judged its value to be dependant on the extent to which there could be such a verb… not, vice versa, that because the form theoretically exists, there must be such a verb. Which really has more worth? "Heed" isn't a bad Answer and I suggest it's not a great one, either. "I was told to sign the check, and I ________ed" isn't a sentence, partly because as  Mari-LouA suggested, "I heeded" lacks an object.

Comment: By the way, how is "I took/to take…" different from "I heeded/to heed…"?