# Take advice vs follow advice

Tags: meaning, word-usage, verbs, differences

To *take advice* is usually defined as:

> obtain information and guidance, typically from an expert.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/take_advice)

By this definition, there is no implication that the advice is actually followed. But can take advice also imply that the advice is actually followed, i.e., put into practice? Are there better expressions to differentiate obtaining information from putting it into practice?

Comment: We say *He got some good advice, but he didn't take it,* to mean that he didn't actually follow it. Find a better dictionary. [See this webpage](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Collocations/T/take_advice_3402.php), for example.

Comment: @PeterShor which dictionary? I checked several.

Comment: Looking at the OED, it looks like the meaning has changed since the nineteenth century, and the dictionaries haven't kept up. So this explains why many good dictionaries get it wrong. [The Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/take) gets it right.

Comment: @PeterShor Even the Collins is not consistent: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/take-advice

Comment: The Collins definition is NOT an idiomatic American usage. I'm intrigued to learn Brits use it this way. (Á là Law and Order and the Miranda rights given in every detective drama, we Americans would "consult" with an attorney.)

Comment: The print *New Oxford American Dictionary* has"*take advice* phrase - obtain information and guidance, typically from an expert" and  "*take someone's advice* act according to recommendations given"

Comment: *Give* by John Newman (1996, [Google books](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Give/NEy3FCWkt6QC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22take+advice%22&pg=PA244&printsec=frontcover)) says on p. 244 that take can mean more than passive acceptance: "Note that the expression *take advice* does not refer to listening to advice being given, but refers rather to accepting the advice and actually acting on the advice. The thing being taken in this case is understood then as not just coming into the sphere of interest of the person but is internalized by the receiver and made part of the receiver's new behaviour."

Comment: Looking through Google books, it appears that despite the OED's definition of *to solicit the opinions of others* and its citations illustrating this meaning, *taking advice* has usually meant acting on it for at least the last 250 years or so.

Comment: I'm gobsmacked that English speakers don't just know that take or follow advice is tsdt. A good antonym is eschew [pronoun if needed] advice.

Comment: Related: [Is “tell advice” not idiomatic over “give advice”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/525349/is-tell-advice-not-idiomatic-over-give-advice) and [Is there a verb for "to take advice"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380712/is-there-a-verb-for-to-take-advice)

Comment: @Lambie what is "tsdt"?

Comment: @Lambie "I'm gobsmacked that English speakers don't just know" consider that for most English speakers it is a second language.

Comment: @Roland The same damn thing. :) Yes, even English speakers who have English as a second language should know this.

Comment: @Lambie Don't underestimate how hard it is to get the nuances of a language for non native speakers. Especially if they don't live in an English speaking country.

Answer (score 3):

To say that one has taken somebody's advice will normally be understood to mean that one has not only heard, understood, and considered the advice, but that, upon considering it, one has determined that the advice is well justified and worthy of being followed. In other words, taking the advice involves embracing the views expressed in the advice as one's own. One can thus say, 'X, Y, and Z had given me different advice on the matter; after thinking about it for a while, I took Y's advice and did this'. In that situation, in which one has rejected X's and Z's advice, it would be misleading to say that one has taken the advice of all three of them, even though it would be true that one has received advice from all of them.

Saying that one has taken somebody's advice still does not, strictly speaking, imply that the advice has already been followed: it may be that the time to implement the advice is still in the future. What it does imply is the intention to act on the advice when the time for so acting arrives. One can say 'I took your advice to go on that trip, and started planning for it, but then got sick and had to cancel it'; in that case the advice to go on the trip hasn't been actually followed, but it is still true that one took the advice in that one formed the intention to follow it.

Sometimes one forms an intention to follow somebody's advice, whatever it turns out to be, before soliciting it. In these scenarios, obtaining the advice merges with taking it, in the above explained sense, which explains why *take advice* may also be understood to stand for obtaining advice. The authors of the quoted dictionary definition probably had such scenarios in mind (note that they say 'typically from an expert', and that seeking expert advice usually involves an intention to follow it).

The explanation offered in the preceding paragraphs does not apply to constructions such as *take somebody's advice seriously*; it is not self-contradictory to say 'I took your advice seriously, but decided to reject it, because it was outweighed by other considerations'. In that sentence, *seriously* doesn't qualify *take somebody's advice* in a straightforward manner; it is rather that *take seriously* functions as an idiom.

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking saying you have taken someone's advice means you have followed it.

Comment: I'm surprised that Peter's findings above didn't prompt an answer. But here, especially as the default sense of 'take someone's advice' appears (as shown in OED) to have changed since the nineteenth century, an answer differing from that given in a reputable dictionary (eg Lexico) needs to be supported by an authoritative reference.

Comment: For me, the key point to make here is that advice doesn't necessarily consist of a description of a particular course of action that _can_ be followed. It might for example just inform one of the potential consequences of various actions. In such a case it might be more informative to say "I took legal advice before deciding what to do" rather than "I followed legal advice", since the latter could be interpreted as meaning that the specific course of action had been recommended.